# Enable Blender openCL compute in linux

Tags: linux, opencl, blender

I have a HP Envy 4 1025tx machine with Ubuntu 12.10.

My blender doesn't seem to detect the dedicated G-Card ATI Radeon 7670m.
But it does detect it on windows. Should I have to install any linux drivers
or does blender doesn't fully support openCL on linux. Or shoulf I manually 
recompile the code?

How should I fix it?

Comment: Try to update drivers with the official Catalyst and AMP APP SDK:
http://developer.amd.com/tools/hc/AMDAPPSDK/downloads/Pages/default.aspx

Comment: That totally wrecks my Unity. I cant launch X server anymore!
I had to switch to tty01 and remove it manually :(

Answer (score 1):

open the terminal and use the command: CYCLES_OPENCL_TEST=true
this enable the opencl support to opencl on blender

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Regardless of if this is correct or not, try to make your answer more than a single sentence (or else just leave it as a comment). For example, tell us where your getting this idea from (personal experience, an external reference, etc.) Also try your best to use good English (capitalization, punctuation, etc.).